# how can we prove the convergence of the integral?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

i tried to maximize this integral with an integral that converges, however i could not find one. Any help

$\phi (n)=(1-x)^{n}e^{-2x}$ 
 and $I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\phi_{n}(x)dx$

Comment: So you want to prove that $I_n$ converges for all natural number $n?$

Answer (score 2):

You may use a constant upper bound, since you are integrating on $[0,1]$. Note
$$
|e^{-2x}(1-x)^n|\leq |(1-x)^n|\leq 1
$$
so it is indeed integrable, 
$$
\int |e^{-2x}(1-x)^n|\mathrm dx\leq \int \mathrm dx=1
$$

Comment: thank you. It was a good help.